# Ruby On Rails Twitter Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to **Ruby On Rails**. I want to create a simple application which has a home page with a **search box** and a **submit button**. The search box is used for searching keywords on **twitter** dynamically. The application connects to twitter, takes all the feeds containing the keyword searched and displays back on the home page of my application. Can anyone please guide me how should i go about it ? I want to create an application from scratch. Please site any example for the same. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,
Bhargav

Comment: This question is too broad. Please use google to find tutorials and come back here when you're stuck and have a [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to start from scratch and not use any gems for it, you should go to the [Twitter API reference](https://dev.twitter.com/), and start from there

I would recomend you use the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)

RailsCasts has a nice episode on it, but the episode for [Twitter Integration](http://railscasts.com/episodes/359-twitter-integration) is not for free.

If you are looking into use Rails for a long time, a subscription is well worth it though.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a small Twitter app from scratch (without the Twitter gem), maybe it is helpful:

https://github.com/sos4nt/jack-of-all-tweets

There's an instance running on Heroku: https://jack-of-all-tweets.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the twitter gem: https://github.com/sferik/twitter